# Profundidade Array

Tags: java, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho um Array a1

```
a1=[a2[a3[a4[]],a5]]
```

Necessito de saber a profundidade do array ora neste caso é 3 porque dentro do array a1 tem o array a2 e dentro do a2 tem o a3 e dentro do a3 tem o a4, ou seja 3 níveis de profundidade.

a profundidade muda de array para array o a1 é a titulo de exemplo

Answer (score 6):

Se entendi bem sua questão, você pode usar uma função recursiva que incrementa um contador a cada vez que encontra um vetor dentro de outro.

Veja um exemplo:

```java
public class ProfundidadeArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //a1=[a2[a3[a4[]],a5]]
        Object[] a5 = null;
        Object[] a4 = { };
        Object[] a3 = {a4};
        Object[] a2 = {a3};
        Object[] a1 = {a2, a5};

        int depth = depth(a1, 0);
        System.out.println(depth);
    }

    public static int depth(Object[] array, int currentDepth) {
        if (array != null && array.length > 0) {
            int result = 0;
            //itera sobre os elementos do array
            for (Object item : array) {
                //verifica se o item é um array
                if (item != null && item.getClass().isArray()) {
                    //chama o método recursivamente, incrementando a "profundidade"
                    int d = depth((Object[]) item, currentDepth + 1);
                    //somente retorna a maior profundidade
                    if (d > result) {
                        result = d;
                    }
                }
            }
            //retorna a maior profundidade encontrada
            return result;
        }
        return currentDepth;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nota: fiz uma mudança sutil que acredito ter deixado o algoritmo um pouco mais simples.